# Preload image with xhr2/blob

Tags: javascript

I want to preload a image with xhr2/blob, because I need a download progress, so I don't want to using new Image() for the preloading, But I not sure the xhr2/blob can it store the cache before next requrest, anynoe know the details? can I using xhr2/blob for preloading? Or it only can use new Image()?

Comment: What do you mean by "preloading"?

Comment: Yes xhr will use the cached version if there is one. No you can not use it to preload your images. Every image loading is asynchronous, even if served from http cache, or blobURI, or dataURI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Yes xhr will use the cached version if there is one.

You can check in the Network panel of your dev tools, or just compare the loading time of these requests :

```js
const url = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png?' + Math.random();
// the same for both requests, but different for each snippets
function requestData(cb){
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  startTime;
  xhr.open('get', url);
  xhr.onload = e => {
    console.log(performance.now() - startTime);
    if(cb){
      cb();
      }
    }
  startTime = performance.now();
  xhr.send();
  }
requestData(requestData);
```

---

#### No you can not use it to preload your images.

Every image loading is asynchronous, even if served from http cache, or blobURI, or dataURI *

```js
fetch('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png')
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      console.log('synchronous', img.naturalWidth, img.complete);
      }
     let img = new Image();
     img.onload = e => console.log('async', img.naturalWidth, img.complete);
     img.src = url;
     });
```

*(At least it should be, some UAs are known to load the resources in a synchronous way if served from cache)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not really understand what you mean, let me confirm that. You mean if I use the xhr to load a image, in the second time I use the xhr to load same image again it will use the cached version? But I use new Image() to load same image it will not use the cached version by xhr. So, I can not use the xhr to preload my images, is my understanding right?

Comment: @Jasper no. Even new Image() will use the http cache version. So you won't have to **dowload** the media again, but this doesn't mean that your image will load synchronously : you will still have to wait for its onload event before it is actually loaded.. (But it will take 10ms instead of 1 second). This i really important if you want e.g dtaw this imahe on a canvas. It is less imotant if you just want to display this image.