# JS new image if not in cache

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob, preload

I'm loading some images via XHR and play them as sequence on canvas element.

I preload images first and after all images are preloaded I call for every image

```
const im = new Image();
im.src = image;
ctx.drawImage(im ,0,0);
```

where **image** is a blob url

The problem is, when animation loops, browser make new requests for every frame. As images are cahced, it takes no time, but continuously builds thousands of requests.

I still can not pass blob url to canvas, as it does not support it, and if I try to path the actual image url, it does not work, because these urls are not preloaded, only the blob urls.

Is there a way to omit request with new Image() if src url is cached?

Thanks

P.S. To clarify

As images are preloaded for the first time, they are actually preloaded
[image]

And as i call new Image() and pass blobUrls as src, they are loaded from cache
[image]

Comment: Load the images and store them in an array. Then play the movie from the array.

Comment: Canvas2D might not, but WebGL certainly allows you to use blob URLs as textures and even (and that's _probably_ far more practical?) lets you assign a stream to a texture, so you aren't working with 1000+ images but a (much smaller) mp4 or something.

Comment: @Mike you mean webgl has a synchronous fetch algorithm in its texture API? Could you point to some resources about it.  Sobakinet, even loading an Image from a blobURI is async anyway. So indeed as correctly said ChrisG, preload your images with img elements and store these elements rather than Blobs (you'll save twice memory usage btw).

Comment: Highly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453031/preload-image-with-xhr2-blob/42454535#42454535

Comment: There are both - blob urls and image urls stored in array. But if I use image urls instead of blob urls, browser loads them again, because only blobs url are preloaded.....

Comment: No blobURLs are prefetched but not preloaded. Store the `<img>` elements instead of urls. You'll even win wrt memory consumption.

Comment: I use this plugin to preload https://www.npmjs.com/package/preload-it. The blobURLs are preloaded. As I create newImage and pass blobUrl as src, browser makes a new request, but loads images from cache. It downloads the actual size, my images take. No double loadings. The problem is multiple requests to cache...

Comment: Kaiido, I think, I've got, what you mean ) To store images, but not urls in array ) Will try it out!